# Drupal 7;Custom Search module NOT returning content found in views

Tags: search, drupal, view

I am using the Custom Search module. If I cut & paste content from my site that is output using a view, the search results do not include any content found in any views.  If I cut & paste content from simple content areas, these items are returned in my search results. Could my custom search NOT be searching individual nodes?  thereby missing the content output using views? If so, how can I configure the custom search module to return all content including that found in views?  Secondly, can the custom search module HIGHLIGHT items that match the search criteria once I navigate to the individual pages returned in the search results? Thank you.

Comment: Generally content that is output in views will be part of a node anyway. Can you be a bit more specific. If you are referring to, for example, arbitrary header or footer content that you're adding to a view, then you will have difficulty having this indexed and hence searchable.

Comment: One of my content pages has a content area located in what is called 'region top'.  This content is successfully indexed and searched.  In an area called 'region bottom', the content is displayed by clicking on a 'toggle' headline.  The content within this toggled area is produced with a view...collecting, sorting and displaying node/field content.  This content is never returned in a search.  I could cut&paste content from one of these areas...insert this into my search area and it is never returned in the search results page.  Neither is content from the left sidebar also created with a view

Comment: @klidifia...does this new information help diagnose my issues?  I would have thought that the default search module should search all nodes whether they are presented as a result of a view or just as directly entered text into the content type